# Why does aes_128_cbc() work but not aes_128_gcm() for encryption/decryption using EVP?

Tags: c, authentication, encryption, openssl, aes-gcm

The code below uses aes_128_cbc and it encrypts the code properly, but when I change it to aes_128_gcm, there is not output encrypted.The code below is my original working code. My key is 128 bits (length 16) and the iv is also length 16 as well.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <openssl/evp.h>
    #include <openssl/aes.h>
    #include <string.h>


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    char key[]="somerandomkey123"; /*length 16*/
    char output[1024];
    char input[]= "Message here.";
    int len;
    FILE *binfile;


    if(!ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()){
        (error message)
    }
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),NULL,key,"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\")){
        (error message)
    }
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx,output,&len,input,strlen(input))){
        (error message)
    }
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, output+len, &len)){
        (error message)
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx)

    /*This prints out 0 when I change cbc to gcm, but prints a correct    size when I use cbc*/
    printf("Output size: %d \n", len);

    /*Properly writes to file when cbc used but not when gcm used. Nothing is in encrypted.bin when gcm is used when encrypted text should be there.*/
    binfile = fopen("encrypted.bin","wb");
    fwrite(outbuf,len,1,binfile);
```

When I change the EVP_aes_128_cbc() to EVP_aes_128_gcm(), the code doesn't work anymore. I also changed the iv to length 12 ("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"). Finally, I added this code block after EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:

```
    char tag[] = "1234567890123456";

    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx,EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG,16,tag)){
        (error message)
    }
```

My final output when printed is of size 0 and nothing is in it (Noted in the original code). My question is why am I not getting any encryption when I only change cbc to gcm? Is it due to key/iv size issues or is it something greater?

Comment: Your original code is not complete. It also has syntax errors. And you did not explain what "does not work" anymore means?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I edited my question and moved stuff around and I may have deleted some info. Above is the code that I have fully (may have missed an include statement), but overall that is what I have. For cbc it works, but changing it to gcm, my output buffer is empty and no encryption occurs in the end. I hope this clarification helps.

Comment: AES encrypts bytes, not strings.  If the first byte turns into `0x00` then `strlen` will report 0.  Don't use `strlen`, use your existing `len` variable.

Comment: stelen is a typo?

Comment: oops, i fixed it. And yeah that was supposed to be strlen. If i were to write the buffer output into a file called encrypted.bin, the file is completely empty. I added that to the question to showcase that.

Comment: I changed the above code so that I use len instead of strlen() within the print statement. However, could I use strlen() in the EVP_EncryptUpdate function as well or would I have to change that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EncryptUpdate and EncryptFinal both add to output buffer (or not). 
By a chance, for your short plaintext message, in CBC mode all of the output is written by EncryptFinal, and for GCM mode all output is written by EncryptUpdate.

The issue in your code is the fact, that you are reusing "len" variable in both EncryptUpdate and EncryptFinal. They both (over)write len by the amount of data added by the call. So in CBC mode EncryptFinal overwrites initial 0 by 16, and in GCM mode initial 13 is everwritten by 0.

You should do as explained in openssl wiki (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption):

```
/* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
 * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
 */
if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
  handleErrors();
ciphertext_len = len;

/* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
 * this stage.
 */
if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) 
  handleErrors();
ciphertext_len += len;
```

BTW:You can keep using strlen for length of your input data, if it's text only, but remember that this will not encrypt zero terminator, so you will have to add it manually after decryption.